# Access strings resources from embedded .resx in dll?

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I'm completely new to resource files, but there is a need for me to deploy my application as click-once, and that seems to ignore all of my external files (images, .ini files etc...) - Rather than spend time trying to figure it out, I thought I'd learn how to use Resource files properly.

After searching through SO, I've found much code and I've built my resource file. So far it only contains strings, which I thought would be simpler!? Alas...

So I've got my DLL (ValhallaLib.dll) and these two functions for dealing with resources (these functions are held within a static Helper Class, where all my random but useful functions live):

```
    public static Bitmap getImageByName(string imgName)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
        var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(resName, asm);

        return (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(imgName);
    }


    public static string getStringByName(string var)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
        var rm = new ResourceManager(resName, asm);

        return rm.GetString(var);
    }
```

And I'm attempting to call them with a simple:

```
CHelpers.getStringByName("db_host_address");
```

Now, other than getting a MissingManifestException... My problem is, that I have no idea (and can't seem to find a straight answer!!) what the  `resName`  should be. My resources file is called: `StringResource.resx` - Yet, its not a case of saying Assembly.ValhallaLib.StringResource.

Can anyone offer some guidance, please?

**Update**
I've tried `global::ValhallaLib.StringResource` - but that's not really what I'm after either.

**Update 2**
Solved it. I've managed to get it to work with:

```
    public static string getStringByName(string var)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
        var rm = new ResourceManager("ValhallaLib.StringResource", asm);

        return rm.GetString(var);
    }
```

I don't know why I found that so overly complicated. Possibly because I've had about 2 hrs sleep.

Cheers to those who tried though :)

Comment: I would like to add that this is redundant in your code `string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";`, I don't see it's used anywhere in the scope of method `getStringByName()`, it should be removed.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct and it's since been removed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*facepalm* I've figured it out. I can access the resources file using

```
    public static string getStringByName(string var)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
        var rm = new ResourceManager("ValhallaLib.StringResource", asm);

        return rm.GetString(var);
    }
```

Ignore me :)

Answer (score 0):

resName is a base name for resources. In your case you can simple use full type name of resource class.

```
var resName = typeof(StringResource).FullName;
```

Comment: Thank you @SergeyIL - I've just managed to solve it myself. Have amended the question. Cheers :)