# How to use localization with data annotation in a separate DTO Assembly (Asp.net Core Web Api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have:

- a **Dto.Library** (.Net 5 Library)
- a **SharedResourceLibrary** with Resource.resx (.Net 5 Library)

How can i use the Resource File Messages in conjunction with Data Annotation in my DTO.Library?

The ErrorMessage should be the text from the resx files:

```
public class MeterForCreationDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name must not be empty!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit must not be empty!")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

SharedResourceLibrary: [looks like this answer @Shiran Dror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167350/localization-in-external-class-libraries-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom attribute for the properties. Something like this:

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute: DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey) 
        : base(GetMessageFromResource(resourceId))
    { }

    private static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceKey)
    {
        // return the translation out of your .rsx files
    }
}
```

and then you need to add

```
public class MeterForCreationDto
{
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("Unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

but you need to add exactly the same key in the attribute which is in your .rsx file. If your searching for "asp.net localizeddisplayname" there are a lot of different sites with examples.

Some help for creating custom attributes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes

Hopefully, it helps. :)

Comment: Hi NiceBone, thank you very much for the answer. But i really dont want to create a new Attribute each time. If there is a need to do so, then i would prefer using fluent.validation and then inject IStringLocalizer in the validation process. I saw ppls using services.AddMVC().AddLocalization(). But this doesnt work for web api.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you more than the method I described above. So far I have done everything with the attribute "LocalizedDisplayName". Maybe someone else has a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
 `[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName ="NameInRecourseFile",ErrorMessageResourceType =typeof(RecourseFileName))]`
also u need to make the Recourse file public from this menu:
[image]
finally u need to have a default Resource file[for your default culture]
 Default resource file name shouldn't have any specific culture (.en،.fr،....)
`SharedService.en.resx => SharedService.resx`
 note .en is the default culture in your app
so it will like these:
`SharedService.resx`[for your default culture]
`SharedService.ar.resx`
`SharedService.fr.resx`
Hope this helped you.
Best wishes.